# Does calculating the limit of a given real-valued (recursive) sequence already imply its convergence?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Assuming we are given a real-valued recursive sequence $(a_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ by its starting point $a_1$ and its recursive function $a_{n+1} = \varphi(a_n)$

EDIT: Since this question caused some confusion or i failed to be clear i'd like to add the recursive sequence:

$$a_1 = \sqrt{2},\ a_{n+1} = \sqrt{2a_n}$$

In order to prove the convergence of $(a_n)_{n}$ i would try to prove boundedness and monotonicity (if that's the case). Then i would try to compute its limit.

However, a few days ago i've been asked whether it would not be sufficient enough to simply compute $$\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$$

without even proving whether or not $(a_n)_n$ is convergent at all.

Ive been asked that if we basically could find an $a$ for which $$ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$$  holds 
we could immediately conclude that the given sequence was convergent in the first place.

I was quite sceptical but i failed to provide a reasonable answer why it would certainly not sufficient enough. My first reaction was that it might be possible that $a$ might not be the limit but only an accumulation point. But i'm not sure if that's either the case or if i'm completely mistaken.

Can you possibly help me with an answer to that question? Can i simply compute $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = a$ prior to proving the existence of such an $a$ at all?

This is all restricted to $\mathbb{R}$ but any general answer is highly appreciated as well.

Thank you very much for any help.

Comment: I do not know what the exact question is. With $\varphi(x) = x^2$ your hypotetical limit will satisfy $a=a^2$ which would give $a=1$ or $a=0$.  But of course the sequence diverges for $|a_1| >1$

Comment: I don't know what you are asking.  A sequence is convergent if and only if the limit exists.  What distinction are you making?

Comment: If $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} a_n$ exists then the sequence converges, but it difficult to see how you *know* it exists just by calculating successive terms which appear to approach a particular value without reaching it

Comment: Sorry for any confusion i might have caused. I will edit my question to provide a sequence

Comment: It's still not clear what you're asking here; I think explaining _how_ you compute the limit would help matters here.  Note that saying e.g. 'the limit is the unique value $L$ satisfying $L=\sqrt{2L}$' isn't actually computation in any relevant sense...

Comment: i'm really sorry. Maybe i used the word "compute" in the wrong way. I would have done it just as you mentioned. The limit is the unique value $a$ satisfying $ a = \sqrt{2a}$. Wouldn't that be the proper way to do it?

Comment: The limit, **if it exists**, is the unique value satisfying $a=\sqrt{2a}$; that's not enough to prove existence in and of itself (and if that's the question you're really asking, then the answer to the question provides a clear counterexample).

Comment: "if we.. could find an a for which
limn→∞an=a
holds we could .. conclude .. the..sequence was convergent."   Well if you find an example of a red elephant then you can conclude you found an elephant, can't you.  $\lim a_n = a$ BY DEFINITION means it is convergent.  So the answer is ... Yes, obviously.  Just like traveling to mars means you can conclude we can get of the earth, and sky diving off a pyramid of Giza proves you exist, or finding a himilayan turnip in the shape of billy joel prove you found a vegetable.

Comment: @StevenStadnicki yes, that was exactly my question. I'm really sorry for any confusion. I tried to be clear as any possible but i didnt manage to do so. I highly appreciate all your comments and help!

Comment: Question:  Who is the man who lives at every address?  Answer:  Me.  I am that man.  I am the only person who lives my address.  So the man who lives at every address can't be anybody else but me.  So I am that man.  So I live at *your* address.  Howdy roomy!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take a sequence $(a_n)$ defined by $a_0=0$ and $a_n=2a_{n-1}+1$. If you assume that the limit $L=\lim_{n\to\infty}(a_n)$ exists then by taking the limit of both sides you get $L=-1$. Does this answer your question?

Comment: this is exactly what i was looking for. i really appreciate every comment and your answer. thank you very much.

Comment: @Zest You are welcome! I’m glad to help.

Comment: one last question: the given sequence isn't convergent since it is not bounded right?

Comment: @Zest The answer is Yes assuming you are working in $\mathbb{R}$, in which case all convergent sequences are bounded.

Comment: yes, i am working in $\mathbb{R}$. So basically this is an example for a sequence that does NOT converge but taking the limit of it provides a real value $L$ for which $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n = L$ holds, right?

Comment: @Zest $L=-1$ is not a limit for the recursively defined sequence in my example. The reasoning is “If the limit of the sequence exists, then it must be $-1$.” But this does not provide with any clue whether the limit exists or not.

Comment: perfect! thank you for your patience. you've been really helpful :-)